# Insert Data into MongoDB Atlas from Python ( from one function to other) - how to insert?

Tags: python, mongodb, oop, web-scraping, crud

I have data scraped from the website and I want to insert it into MongoDB. Need help on how and where exactly can I do that to insert data? also, I want to insert data and create a collection on the fly in DB.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import re


def print_hi(name: object) -> object:
# Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press ⌘F8 to toggle the breakpoint.
```

constructor

```
class ConfirmedCases:
def __init__(self, id, county, province_state, country_region, lat, lon, date, value):
    self.id = id
    self.county = county
    self.province_state = province_state
    self.country_region = country_region
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.date = date
    self.value = value
```

to iterate rows since the date is updated in new column daily

```
def collection():
url_confirmed = "link1 specified separately"
confirmed_df = pd.read_csv(url_confirmed)
confirmed_cases = []
pattern = "10/.*/.*"
re.compile(pattern)
tester = re.compile(pattern)
dates = []
for col in confirmed_df.columns:
    if tester.match(str(col)) is not None:
        dates.append(str(col))

for index, row in confirmed_df.iterrows():
    county = row['Admin2']
    state = row['Province_State']
    region = row['Country_Region']
    latitude = row['Lat']
    longit = row['Long_']
    id = str(county) + str(state) + str(region)
    for date in dates:
        value = row[date]
        confirmed = ConfirmedCases(id, county, state, region, latitude, longit, date, value)
        confirmed_cases.append(confirmed)
return confirmed
```

function to connect to mongoDB

```
def connection_mongo():
client = MongoClient('link to atlas')
print(client.list_database_names())
db = client.mydata 
coll = db["cc"]
try:
    print("MongoDB version is %s" %
          client.server_info()['version'])
except 
   pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as error:

    print(error)

    quit(1)


collection()
connection_mongo()
```

Comment: Hello Folks, I am web scrapping from a CSV file which is updated daily by John Hopkins University on COVID 19 cases.  It adds a number of confirmed cases daily in a new column which I am able to iterate and convert it into rows properly. I now want to insert this data into the MongoDB atlas. Can you please help me and let me know how can I insert this data in MongoDB? and where should I do this? in a new function or in the same function? since I have established a connection in a new function and my data processing is happening in some other function.

Comment: Link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv '